# Storing output into a dictionary

Tags: powershell

I want to iterate through the folders inside the patch scripts, find every iterated result of DBChangesMain and ContentLbl and store it into a dictionary or hash table, and then print out the results how do i do this?

So far I have

```
$patchscripts = Get-Item "F:\folder\trunk\Source\Database\Patch Scripts" 

foreach ($folders in Get-childitem $patchscripts -recurse -include *.sql )
{        
    if ($folders -like "*DBChangesMain*")
    {   

    }
    if ($folders -like "*ContentLbl*")
    {       

    }      
}

 Write-Host $DbChanges
 Write-Host $contentlbl
```

if you have a better way of doing this, please let me know, cheers.

Comment: What should be your keys and values in the hash table here?

Comment: Key would be DBChanges or contentlbl and the value would be the result of the folder iteration. I'm not sure if i need a hash table, i could even store it into an array i just need to store the outputs of the recursive action in the same variable

Comment: i want to store each returned value which contains DBchangesmain and contentlbl into either the same variable or two variables which i can reference later in my powershell script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess after your comments I'd rather go the following route:

```
$patchscripts = 'F:\folder\trunk\Source\Database\Patch Scripts'
$dbChangesMain = Get-ChildItem $patchScripts -Rec -Inc *DBChangesMain*.sql
$contentLbl = Get-ChildItem $patchScripts -Rec -Inc *ContentLbl*.sql
```

Afterwards you simply have two arrays containing the matching names of the SQL files.

Comment: Generally in PowerShell I advise people to stay away from the explicit iteration constructs, such as `for` or `foreach`. Oftentimes there is a more elegant and readable solution using the pipeline. Most of the time I encounter `foreach` from people approaching PowerShell as if it were just VBScript or C# with a different syntax.

Comment: I have done a bit ov c# so that's where I was coming from, but i'll take this into consideration, powershell seems great so far, looking to see how far I can stretch it.

Comment: I believe foreach loops(without pipeline) are easier to read. They are also faster then pipelines when the array is static. However, pipelined foreach loops are more efficient when the source is coming from a stream(ex. A command that's generating the array you're looping through)

Comment: Graimer, PowerShell is basically a system for modelling dataflows. If you have stuff (whether that's a static array or a stream or a generator makes little difference) you have to put through filters, transformations, etc. I'd argue that it's often vastly easier to read and understand when written with a pipeline. And heck, it's an interpreted scripting language – runtime efficiency is non-existant. To me at least idiomatic PowerShell code avoids `foreach` in favour of a pipeline. The pipeline is easier to extend, you can cut it up in the middle and get intermediate results, etc.